# Doctrine result cache not working in Symfony 5.1

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

i'm using Symfony 5.1 + API Platform, I've activated doctrine result cache using local Memcached but it's not saving any key. It is working ok for metadata and query cache.

NOTE: I've 2 custom bundles with different connections and i'm using Bundle One as default.
I've configured metadata and query cache as result_cache_pool just to check if it's working ok (and it is, memcached is being populated with metadata and parsed queries).

I've tried this using dev and prod environement (always locallay).
I've also tried to manually add the cache driver to the query but still nothing.

```
$cacheDriver = new MemcachedCache();
$queryBuilder->getQuery()->setResultCacheDriver($cacheDriver);
```

cache.yaml

```
framework:
  cache:
    app: cache.adapter.memcached
    pools:
      doctrine.result_cache_pool:
        adapter: cache.app
        default_lifetime: 3600
```

doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: one
    connections:
      default:
        url: "%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%"
      one:
        url: "%env(resolve:DATABASE_ONE_URL)%"
      two:
        url: "%env(resolve:DATABASE_TWO_URL)%"
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    default_entity_manager: one
    entity_managers:
      one:
        metadata_cache_driver:
          type: pool
          pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool
        query_cache_driver:
          type: pool
          pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool
        result_cache_driver:
          type: pool
          pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool
        connection: one
        mappings:
          OneBundle:
            is_bundle: true
            type: annotation
            dir: "Entity"
            prefix: 'Mine\OneBundle'
            alias: Mine\OneBundle
      two:
        ...
```

Comment: Ok, it looks like it's not a magic solution, that activating result_cache_driver won't just cache all doctrine query results. I need to add $qb->getQuery()->enableResultCache(3600);
I can't confirm that seeing the docs, but if this is OK i would have to rewrite findBy method to add that call.

Answer (score 1):

Although this one is a bit old, I'm going to suggest the configuration I managed to make it work, since I was struggling a lot with it, and I found very little information about it. Mine is working with Redis, but it is the same concept.

doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
.......
orm:
.......
    metadata_cache_driver:
        type: pool
        pool: doctrine.second_level_cache_pool
    query_cache_driver:
        type: pool
        pool: doctrine.second_level_cache_pool
    result_cache_driver:
        type: pool
        pool: doctrine.second_level_cache_pool
    second_level_cache:
        enabled: true
        region_lifetime: 30
        region_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.second_level_cache_pool
```

cache.yaml

```
framework:
cache:
    app: cache.adapter.redis
    default_redis_provider: redis://redis:6379
    pools:
        doctrine.second_level_cache_pool:
            adapter: cache.app
```

And finaly, an attribute (or anotation) in the entity class definition:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: PersonRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Cache(usage: 'NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE')]
class Person
{
```